# C++ find method not working

Tags: c++, string, methods, find

I am quite new to c++ so my apologies for the lack if knowledge,however for some reason, my find method isn't working. Any help would be great, here is the code I'm using.

www.pastie.org/9434690

```
//String s21 
string s21 ="| o |";  

if(s21.find("1")){
    cout << "IT WORKS OMG " << s21 << endl;
}
else if(!s21.find("1")){
    cout << "HASOSDKHFSIF" << endl;
}
```

Thanks

Forgot to mention, the code always prints "IT WORKS"  even though there's no "o" in the string.

Comment: Look at a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) for `std::string::find`. This step should always come before SO. It's faster for one.

Answer (score 8):

The issue here is your if statement. `s21.find("1")` will return the index of the first occurrence in the string of the string to match. If it doesn't find a match it returns `string::npos` which is an enumeration of the value `-1`. If statements will return true on all numbers that are not equal to zero. So you need to test it against `string::npos` like this:

```
if(s21.find("1") != std::string::npos)
{
    cout << "IT WORKS OMG " << s21 << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "HASOSDKHFSIF" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The Return value of [*`std::string::find`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is position of the first character of the found substring or [*`std::string::npos`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) if no such substring is found.

You should use *`std::string::npos`* for string matching

```
if(s21.find("1") != std::string::npos )
{
    cout << "IT WORKS OMG " << s21 << endl;
}
else 
{
    cout << "HASOSDKHFSIF" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a little clever, `std::string::npos` is the largest `unsigned int`, or `1111 1111 1111 1111` in binary (people sometimes compare str.find() to the int -1, though it's not recommended). You can take advantage of this bit pattern with a little [***bitwise manipulation***](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/bitwise_operators.html).

Flipping all of the bits will give you nonzero values for every bit pattern EXCEPT `std::string::npos`, and since C++ treats all nonzero values as `true`, your if could actually be:

```
if(~s21.find("1"))
{
    cout << "IT WORKS OMG " << s21 << endl;
}
else if(!~s21.find("1"))
{
    cout << "HASOSDKHFSIF" << endl;
}
```